# sdelete error: "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: sdelete

I am running sdelete in a Windows 10 x64 virtual machine (VirtualBox). I want to remove empty space so I can compact the virtual disk.

I open an admin command prompt in the VM, change directory to the sdelete folder, and run

```
sdelete64.exe -z c:
```

Or

```
sdelete64.exe c: -z
```

I get the error message in the title. It pops up in a blue box.
Then cmd says "Access is denied"

Alternatively, is there another way to write zeroes to free space, besides with sdelete? I read that ccleaner can do it, but the latest version removed the option to wipe only the free space, because there were complaints that it wiped too much.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot. Are you sure the VM has a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: See the screenshot I added, it shows the issue and also the bitness of the system.

Comment: Why not just use the normal [`sdelete.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete)? _(There's likely a benefit to the 64bit version in certain scenarios, but what those might be I've never come across)_

Comment: I get the same error with the normal sdelete.exe

Comment: What’s the file size of `sdelete64.exe`?

Comment: Aha. 0 bytes. I wonder how that happened. I ran sdelete successfully less than 24 hours before my unsuccessful try.